# How to choose the name of key in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I choose the name of the key in Firebase Realtime Database?

[this is my database now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEis.png)

The key here is automatically generated (-LiNph8fnLlcDTkLqq_K). How can I choose its name?

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.child("Data").push().setValue("some value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` method will generate a random id. If you want to choose your own id then you can do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.child("Data").child("firstData").child("value").setValue("some value");
```

Then you would have:

```
Data
  firstData
      value : some value
```

But it is better if you use `push()` since you cannot have the same `key` twice in your database.

Find the docs for saving data [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: yes but how can I keep adding new items without replacing the previous item?

Comment: depends what you want to do, but you probably need to increment the value inside the child.., you can add it inside a for loop and then do `child(String.valueOf(i))` for example...

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getListFromFirebaseDbByID(formDataID : String, formListener: SingleFormDataDBListener) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val rootRef = database.child(Constant.FIREBASE_DATABASE)

        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val children = snapshot!!.children.iterator()

                while (children.hasNext()) {
                    val currentItem = children.next()

                    val map = currentItem.getValue() as HashMap<String, Any>
                    val id = map.get("id") as String?

                }

            }
        })
    }
```